# How do I start this Boolean Code?

Tags: java, boolean

I need to write a Java program that involves the following:

Prompts the user for the following information and stores the input in appropriate variables:

Whether the user is left-handed

Whether the user's father was at least 5 ft 10 inches tall

The user's age in months

Prints out the following information, using either `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` or `System.out.println()` for the output:

a) Whether the user is left-handed

b) Whether the user's father was at least 5 ft 10 inches tall

c) Whether at least one of the values from a and b are true (true if either or both are true)

d) Whether a and b are both true (false if at least one is false)

e) Whether the truth values of a and b are the same (true if both a and b are true or if both a and b are false)

I am new to programming and am not sure where to begin.

Comment: [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is your friend. It is used to retrieve information from the console. Also, if your using the `JOptionPane`, make sure to import `javax.swing.JOptionPane` into your program.

Comment: @fireshadow52 - don't confuse the guy with gratuitous advice.  (Hey, if gratuitous advice was a good idea, I could produce **pages** of advice on style, which library methods to use, the pointlessness of micro-optimizing, etcetera, etcetera.)

Answer (score 10):

[Hello World!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) is always a good place to start.  It will teach you how to create a java program, compile it, and run it.  From there, you are going to need to figure out how to

[read things from the command line](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=79),
[convert Strings to Booleans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#Boolean%28java.lang.String%29), and
[use conditional statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Don't want to give you the answer directly since this sounds like homework.

However, if you have code, and run into a specific problem getting your program to compile or run correctly, you can create a question with

1) well formatted code, and
2) the output/exception if applicable
3) other relevant information

and people will try to help...

Comment: +1 for the relevant and helpful links.

Comment: +1 - This is the *best kind of answer* for questions like this where the main agenda is learning to program.  (I'd also add that the OP's course textbook and/or course notes should be able to answer these questions.)

Comment: @stephen thanx.  Give a man a fish, he eats for a day, teach him to fish, ...